# Animate transitions on Hover (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, transition

I'm a jQuery noob, yet i'm trying to figure out how to create an animated transition of a headline.

I have found this CodePen (http://codepen.io/ansac/pen/BHtkE) but this is not exactly what i'm trying to achieve. My question is how can i leave the background on hover as it is, yet animate the text that appears in the middle. I would be very interested in how to animate it horizontally (so that it comes from left/right and stops at the given position (center)) or vertically (from top/bottom) to center.

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for others to write code for you.  Please make an attempt yourself and then come back with a more specific question.

Comment: This might be true, but since my knowledge in Javascript is null (and have no starting point) i was looking into a solution that someone might have achieved already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did try to mess a bit with the link you attached.  Animate most likely will work, but you'll have to mess with your CSS and position settings to find the right placement and tweaking (assuming you're coding similar to this page).  Check it out below and confirm if this is what you're looking for.

**Note:** In the CSS, I changed the text-align for hovertext to LEFT rather than CENTER, and added the animate options for the jQuery.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxlHm

I'm kind of in the same boat as you, learning jQuery/javascript as I go, but just search for some good books/sites to help you along.   jQuery's site is fairly decent to get a good start, as I started looking there.

Comment: Hey, that's exactly what i was looking for! I started digging into the .animate() function as suggested above but with no success so far. Thanks a lot for your solution but there's a small issue i still face - it actually takes a half a second for the text to reach the point. And it's not the speed set for fadeIn, most likely it's the time it takes the text to reach the "0 pixel" border where the image itself starts. I have looked into a bit into it and reduced the margin-left to the most optimal one (-80px) and set the speed as  150ms - i can still notice this "pause". Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: No problem!  I'm not at the point where I can look further into it, but glad you're on the right path.

Answer (score -2):

can you just look the Jquery Animate method, for example, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: Not really wrong, but not really an answer.  And I would really suggest linking to jquery's own documentation instead of w3schools.

Comment: you mean jQuery.com documentation?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: what I thought, for a beginner w3schools example is good, ok